# How to change NavigationBarItemColors of Material Theme 3 Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying to modify bottom navigation bar Item color of Theme Material 3, but when I create new
**NavigationBarItemColors**

```
val myNavigationBarItemColors: NavigationBarItemColors = NavigationBarItemColors(

Cannot access '<init>': it is internal in 'NavigationBarItemColors'
```

I know that class is internal

```
class NavigationBarItemColors internal constructor(
```

Are there any way to custom this theme Navigation color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way by use NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors function

```
colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
  selectedIconColor=Color(0xFF03dac5),
  selectedTextColor = Color(0xFF03dac5),
  indicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
  unselectedIconColor = Color.White,
  unselectedTextColor = Color.White,
  disabledIconColor = Color.Cyan,
  disabledTextColor = Color.Cyan,
),
```